# Is it possible to do OCR in perl AND windows?

Tags: perl, ocr, cpan

The only library I've found that could do that is "Image::OCR::Tesseract", but it doesn't support windows.

Is there any alternative to to that?

Comment: https://metacpan.org/search?q=OCR turns up a few results; some of them pass their unit tests on Windows.

Comment: I once used Cygwin (getting Linux/Gnu tools on Windows, like `gcc`, `make` and `perl` for cygwin) and compiled tesseract there: https://vorba.ch/2014/tesseract-cygwin.html If the perl module doesn't run in Windows, you can run tesseract in perl inside cygwin like this: `system("tesseract -l eng input.tif output") == 0 or die "ERROR: $? $!"`

Answer (score 2):

Looking at CPAN, Tesseract seems to be the extent of serious OCR systems with Perl wrappers.

You might want to check out: 
[Perl Image::OCR::Tesseract module on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19431336/perl-imageocrtesseract-module-on-windows)

Comment: I'm glad people are still getting use out of that post. Sadly, I never did get a reply from that module author, so I think that module is truly in an abandoned state now :(